# R: Sampling observations by factors using tapply

Tags: r, split, sample, lapply

I have a large data set I am attempting to sample rows from. Each row has a family ID, and there may be one or multiple rows for each family ID. I want to parse the data set by randomly sampling one row for each family ID. I have attempted to accomplish this by using both `tapply()` and `split()` + `lapply()` functions, but to no avail. Below is code that reproduces my issue - the size and scope of the factor levels and data entries mirror the data set I am working with.

```
set.seed(63)
f1 <- factor(c(rep(30000:32000, times=1), 
               rep(30500:31700, times = 2), 
               rep(30900:31900, times = 3)))
f2 <- factor(rep(sample(1:7, replace = TRUE), times = length(f1)/7))
x1 <- round(matrix(rnorm(length(f1)*300), nrow = length(f1), ncol = 300),3)
df <- data.frame(f1, f2, x1)
```

Next, I used `tapply` to sample one row per factor from `f1`, and then check for repeats. (`f2` is a secondary factor that indexes another aspect of the observations, but is [hopefully] irrelevant here; I only include it for full disclosure of the structure of my data set).

```
s1 <- tapply(1:nrow(df), df$f1, sample, size=1)
any(duplicated(s1))
```

The output for the second line of code using `duplicated` is `TRUE`, which means there are repeats. Stumped, I tried `split` to see if that was the problem.

```
df.split <- split(1:nrow(df), df$f1)
any(duplicated(df.split))
```

The output here for `duplicated` is `FALSE`, so the problem is not `split`. I then used the output `df.split` with `lapply` and `sample` to see if the problem was with `tapply`.

```
df.unique <- unlist(lapply(df.split, sample, size = 1, replace = FALSE, 
                           prob = NULL))
any(duplicated(df.unique))
```

In the first line, I sampled one value from each element of `df.split` which outputs a list, then I used `unlist` to convert into a vector. The output for `duplicated` here is also `TRUE`.

Somewhere within `sample` and `lapply` there is funky stuff going on (since `tapply` merely calls `lapply`). I'm not sure how to fix the issue (I searched SO and Google and found nothing related to my issue), so any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I'm hoping someone could tell me why the above code using `tapply` and `lapply` is not working as intended. Arthur has provided a nice answer, and I have coded a loop for `sample` as well. I'm wondering why the above code is misbehaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(df)[,.SD[sample(.N,1)],by='f1']
```

... but actually your original approach with `tapply` is faster if you just want an index and not the actual subset table ; however, you must notice that `sample(n)` actually samples in `1:n` when `length(n)==1`. See `?sample`. This version is error-proof:

```
 s1 <- tapply(1:nrow(df), list(df$f1), function(v) v[sample(1:length(v), 1)])` is error prooff
```

Comment: `.SD` is a subset of the table for each value of `f1`, and `.N` is the number of rows of this subset.

Comment: data.table should be as fast as anything available in base R

Comment: I mean something faster... in `data.table`!

Comment: Thanks Arthur. I'm wondering why my code is not working and not sampling in `tapply` (or `lapply`) as intended. Is there a specific reason why my code is giving me repeats?

Comment: `s1 <- tapply(1:nrow(df), df$f1, sample, size=1)` does not work because of `sample(x)` samples in `1:x` when `length(x)==1`. I've be once told it's a classical mistake! (and hence a poor choice of default behaviour...)

Comment: Great, this explains the issue I was having, thank you.